# Unable to receive click events from my Button ImageView, have HomeScreen extending MyActivity

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener

I am not receiving click events from my Buttons. I wonder why.

I have a LinearLayout, with a include layout on the top for the action bar, and below I have a button. I am not able to receive events for

1. the "mylocation icon" on the action bar, right below
2. the Next button
3. the zoom in / out buttons

What am I missing here?

[image][image]

**Main Layout location.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/actionbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        <!-- removed unnecesary attr's -->        
        android:background="#f6461d"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Next"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Action Bar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#EEeeeee4"
    <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> >

    <LinearLayout
        <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/icruiseon"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:background="@drawable/curbcablogo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:background="@drawable/refresh" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/connectStatus"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:src="@drawable/disconnect" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/busy"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:clickable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/busy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscriberInbox"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:background="@drawable/incomingprovider" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's -->  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentAddress"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:text="Receiving address....." />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/whereAmI"
            <!-- removed unnecesary attr's --> 
            android:src="@drawable/mylocation" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My activity file**

```
public class MyActivity {
onCreate() {
    setContentView(R.layout.location) ;

        next = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        whereAmI = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.whereAmI);
        whereAmI.setOnClickListener(this) ;

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == next) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "searching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            new Search(this, source, destination).execute(null);
        } else if (v == whereAmI) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "centering", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            location.getController().setCenter(source);
            new GetGeoAddress(this, source).execute(null);
        }
    }
```

**AnotherActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends MyActivity {
onCreate() {
      //No setContentView here ; I expect that the super class MyActivity will setContentView.
```

Edit : Removed the MapView from layout and code, to eliminate and debug. I still dont get click events. What am I missing here ?

Edit 2 : Added somemore changes above, I suspect this has something to do with Activity Inheritance. I know I am missing something basic here. What is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Inheritance between Activities confuses the onClickListner.

**SuperClass**

```
public class SuperClass extends Activity implements OnClickListner {
     public onCreate() {
         setContentView(R.layout.layoutwithView_ABC) ;
         ABC.setOnClickListener(this) ;
     ...
     public void onClick() {
         Toast ("this wont show up") ;
     }
     ...
}
```

**SubClass, as the first activity on Manifest file**

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements OnClickListner {
     public onCreate() {
         //NOT init here, setContentView(R.layout.layoutwithView_ABC) ;
     ...
     public void onClick() {
         Toast ("will show up") ;
     }
     ...
}
```

Hope I have represented the answer correctly. Even when I have setOnClickListerer for ABC in superclass, the onClick of SubClass is called, since its "Override", Simple Answer.